# What is the Virtual Key (VK) code for special keys (e.g. Print Screen, Scroll Lock, and Pause/Break)?

Tags: java, keylistener

Within the `KeyListener` you have `VK_W` for the 'W' key. But what about those keys above the Insert, Home, Page Up, etc?

Out of curiosity, in case I might use it in the future, what's the VK key code for Print Screen, Scroll Lock, and Pause/Break, if they even have one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VK_PRINTSCREEN`, `VK_SCROLL_LOCK`, and `VK_PAUSE`.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html